# What's the mature solution for label placement?

Tags: labeling

I am working on an android map application, while I need to place the labels for points/lines/polygons manually.

I have googled and I found this:

https://www.ads.tuwien.ac.at/research/labeling/

But it seems that it is last updated at 2004, I am not sure if this manner is out of date. And further more, it just lable the points, while I need to other kind of feature like line,polygon.

So I wonder if there is a better solution?

---

Maybe I do not make myself clear enough.

I am not looking for what should be placed in the map but how to make the features in the map labeled easy readable and without overlap.

Comment: That link looks quite good with cluttered label placement, it's about what you'd get out of maplex.

Comment: It depends on what is important on the map - 1996 research http://www.merl.com/publications/docs/TR96-04.pdf

Comment: That's such a good document @Mapperz, in reality the principles of cartographic placement haven't changed in *decades*, I still refer to a document released in the 1960's on the subject. There's a lot of code in implementing the document and it's not an off-the-shelf solution but you could pick a few pointers out of it and get some great labels if the user is prepared to do some work.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson: You mentioned that there are a lot of implementing for that, any live example?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. If you're after cartographic principles start by googling that, I did and found a few straight away eg: http://www.gsd.harvard.edu/gis/manual/style/

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite new framework for rendering maps. It is called [MapSurfer.NET](http://openmapsurfer.uni-hd.de/Framework/info.html) and it is absolutely free. The labeling algorithms inside are based on the recent research in field of automated labeling. This framework can produce cartographically plausible label placement which is comparable to the output produced by Maplex. Unfortunately, currently the framework runs only on Windows. However, in theory it can work on Android using [Mono](http://xamarin.com/platform). But this feature is only in the plans.

If the use of pre-rendered images (tiles) in your Android application is the case, then you can give it a try.

Please also note that the this framework lacks documentation.

Comment: Some live examples can be found at http://www.openmapsurfer.uni-hd.de/?zoom=10&lat=53.21776&lon=5.47033&layers=B00000FFFF